# How to verify and validate parsed Google Protobuf v2 file

Tags: protocol-buffers, verification, linkage

First, I'll just couch this in the acknowledgement, yes, I am aware of `protoc`, but I've got a specific requirement to extrapolate some specialized target language artifacts based on a *.proto* file parser outcome.

That being established, I've already got the parser itself working. I am working on resolving imported *.proto* dependencies. Not a terribly difficult endeavor on the surface, in and of itself.

The next steps after that, I think, are to perform a kind of "transitive linkage", as I've learned, but I am curious what I should be aware of. Prima facie, I think I should be collating a set (most likely map) of element paths to field numbers, as well as collating the reserved as well as extensions, then perhaps verifying as I traverse the *.proto* dependency tree.

However, I'd like to get an idea of others' experience, guidance, feedback, along these lines.

For what I'm wanting to accomplish, I do not think this verification step needs to be that elaborate, only enough to rule out invalid *.proto*, etc.

Oh. last but not least, I need to handle this for Protobuf v2 language spec.

Comment: I'd just use protoc's FileDescriptorSet output. It can output the parsed file in protobuf format, which you can then more easily generate anything you want from.

Comment: @jpa Thank you for the response; this seems like a fairly niche question to investigate. I'm not sure what you mean by "it can output the parsed file in protobuf format". Can you elaborate a little please? This is one of the areas of confusion for me, blocking me from being completely sold that ``protoc`` quite fits what I am trying to accomplish. Specifically, what parsed file? What is in protobuf format?

Comment: @jpa To explain further, I am given the ``.proto`` that I want to parse, and extrapolate additional target language bits that will enhance an already generated ``.proto`` target language output. So, to be clear, I do not need the "basic" target language output. That is already there for me to work with. I am seeking to generate some bits that will enhance that target language experience.

Comment: To get started, you could try this: `protoc -o test.pb test.proto` `protoc --decode=google.protobuf.FileDescriptorSet -I / /usr/include/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto < test.pb`  which will show you what data is available from there.